# iphone to ipad conversion: some storyboard options missing

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard

I'm converting an iphone app to an ipad app.  I've changed the project's build target from "iphone" to "ipad" and the app compiles, builds, runs and displays the way I want it to.

However, I've noticed that some parts of Storyboard still believe this is an iphone app.  For example, when I try to build a segue, it only offers me the "push" "modal" and "custom" options.  A newly created ipad project also offers the "popover" and "replace" options. 
Similarly, this converted app does not offer me the possibility of a Split View Controller.

So is there a setting or some way to get this "iphone" -> "ipad" app to have the full ipad storyboard options without restarting the project and copying everything over?

Comment: I find this that could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/convert-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this awhile back. I fixed it by **clicking on my main project** on the navigation panel. If you go to **summary** and look under the **iOS Application Development** you will see a spot that asks which **devices** your app is targeted to. Make sure this is switched to **universal**

Next create an iPad storyboard under File > new > File... > User Interface > Storyboard > set **Device Family** to **iPad** (It sounds like you already did this though). Make sure you call it something different then your iPhone storyboard.

Lastly go back to your project settings and scroll down to the **iPad Development Info** you will see a drop down titled **Main Storyboard**. Make sure that is set to your newly created iPad storyboard.

If this still is not working for you the Standford ItunesU iOS course has a lecture on converting iPhone applications to universal ones.