# Storyboard issue in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, storyboard, ios8, viewcontroller

i am developing ios 8 app using swift. i got some problem with viewcontroller layout in the storyboard. when i add the viewcontroller, i only get iphone size but not ipad size. my app is only focus on ipad not even universal application. i checked size in "simulated metrics" but there is no size for ipad except all iphone sizes.

[image]

but i create new storyboard and add the viewcontroller. there is no totally issue at all. so what happened to my existing storyboard? and how can i fix it?

Thanks,
frog

Comment: What devices did you choose in Project Settings, iPhone, iPad or Universal?

Comment: Me too, but mine shows up as: http://i.imgur.com/ZL0c2d8.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877113/xcode-storyboard-why-does-the-ipad-storyboard-show-iphone-sized-views

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the storyboard in the Project navigator. Use the File inspector and enable Size Classes (it's a checkbox). That solves it.

If you really don't like enabling Size Classes, now disable Size Classes again - but when the dialog appears, specify that you want to keep the iPad size class data. (Really, though, you should be using Size Classes if this is an iOS 8 app.)

Comment: i cannot use Size Classes because i used customized segue. It will effect my segues. right?

Comment: Look. You asked how to see the iPad size listed in the pop-up menu. The way I told you is the way to do that. If you don't want to do that, fine. But then you aren't going to see the iPad size listed. Why not just use Freeform and size it yourself, then? Sheesh.

Comment: bro , i think XCode refresh problem.