# Create iPad storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to create a iPad UI for an existing iPhone app. I've created a storyboard for iPad and added a main iPad UI in the project file to

MainiPad

but it still just shows the iPhone layout, not sure what I missed. Can anyone help me figure out what step I missed?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can change screen size what you want need to use also you can check this content

[Xcode storyboard: Why does the iPad storyboard show iPhone sized views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877113/xcode-storyboard-why-does-the-ipad-storyboard-show-iphone-sized-views?rq=1)