# how to keep same iPhone app dimension in iPad during debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dimension

I only have an iPad, but I have developed a iPhone 5 app, and wanna to test it though iPad.

The issue is that frame and all objects are expanding to full screen in ipad.

I used IOS 5.1, iPad 1, Xcode 4.6.1, storyboard(iphone), set ipad use the same storyboard as iphone in "target".

So please help me how to run the same iphone size app in the ipad.

Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: Where possible - remove all autoresizing and set up static sizes. That should do it for most of the UI.

Comment: Yes, u'r right. Sometimes UI bothers me a lot~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to change the app target from Universal to iPhone.
(check sample image)

**Go to:** `[Project Targets] > Summary > iOS Application Target > Devices > iPhone`

[image: Sample Image]

This way the iPad will open your app as a legacy iPhone app.

(This worked for me in a simple example, but there may also be more work involved in ensuring you are building for iPhone only and not using any iPad-only UI elements.)