# iPhone project defaults to iPad view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard, ios-universal-app

I normally create apps for the iPad, but I decided to make one for the iPhone. When creating the project, I told XCode that this was targeted at the iPhone. After creating the project, the target/devices/everything says that it is being built for the iPhone. However, in the storyboard, every view controller defaults to iPad size/dimensions. How do I tell the project to default to iPhone size?

Also how do I change the storyboard files already created to the correct dimensions (without hard coding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, when you create a new storyboard file (File -> New -> File... -> User Interface -> Storyboard), Xcode prompts you to select a device family for the storyboard.  Just select iPhone instead of iPad.

Changing an existing storyboard is trickier, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/convert-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad) should provide you with a solution to do that if just making a new file will take too long.