# ios - iPad emulator seems to have height that is too much

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I followed the advice of this question: 
[Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/convert-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)

and it worked, but my iPad screens seem to be too tall...maybe about 150% too tall.  And the user has to scroll down to see the UITabBar.

Would anyone happen to know why that happened and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds that the simulator is just too big for your monitor. Try going to the Window menu and changing the scale to something smaller. You could also try setting the device to the  non-retina iPad.

[image: Window Menu]