# iPad simulator/device uses iPhone storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

So I've created an app for iPhone and I wanted to convert it to iPad, by following steps from  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/convert-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad).

- Duplicate your iPhone-Storyboard and rename it MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard
- Open this file any text editor.
- Search for targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"and change it to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
- Now save everything and reopen Xcode -> the iPad-Storyboard contains the same as the iPhone-file but everyting could be disarranged

Everything is done correctly but iPad simulator/device anyways uses iPhone storyboard. Any suggestions?

I've set iPad storyboard in summary->ipad deployment info->Main storyboard. And  main.plist-> Main storyboard file base name (iPad) is set to iPad storyboard.

Please tell me what I am missing.

**UPD**. Interesting Thing, when I delete iPad storyboard name from ipad deployment info it still uses my iPhone storyboard on device.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean Xcode uses iPhone storyboard?  When you build for the iPad simulator, it still uses the iPhone storyboards?

Comment: yea, ipad simulator/device uses the iPhone simulator

Comment: Under iOS Application Target, is Devices set to Universal?

Comment: yea, Application target is set to universal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always pick the proper storyboard in the appDelegate and present the appropriate root view controller programatically

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIViewController *rvc;
}
```

Implementation

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"IPAD_Storyboard" bundle:nil];
       rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierForController"];
    }
    else {
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
       rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierForController"];
    }


    [self.window addSubview:rvc.view];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: not the most xcode-y way to do it, but you seemed to have problems with that route :/, glad i could help.

Comment: This is outdated. Replace the addSubview line with: [self.window setRootViewController:rvc];

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget to add following things in project's info.plist file (Main Storyboard file base name/ Main Storyboard file base name (iPad))

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, info-> Main storyboard file base name (iPad) is set to iPad storyboard.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Xcode set Main nib file base name (iPad) to Main-iPad.storyboard instead of the correct Main storyboard file base name (iPad) when I upgraded the app to universal.