# What is the best way to reuse views between iPhone and iPad storyboards?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app, xcode-storyboard

I am making a universal app with different storyboards for iPhone and iPad. Some of my view controllers have the same exact layout in the iPhone and iPad versions (they are either added as subview controllers or presented modally).

I am contemplating how I can define these layouts once so that I [don't repeat myself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). As far as I see it I have two options to make this work:

1. Define the views twice in the different storyboards. In this case, I get full segue storyboard functionality.
2. Define the views in separate `.xib` files. In that case, I need to capture click events and manually call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` on my storyboard.

Are there any other options? Is one of these preferred over the other?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad

Comment: @KHansenSF that's only tangentially related to what I'm trying to do.