# Copying single iPhone view controller to iPad view controller gives lock icon/ doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I had an iPhone only app which I recently converted to Universal.  I followed the excellence advice in this question to copy over the storyboard.

[Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)

Now, I created a new custom UIViewController for a new feature for my app.  I did it in the iPhone storyboard.  As a result, I want to copy that UIViewController to the iPad storyboard.  I can follow the above steps again, but that seems like overkill.  What I want to do is copy and paste the iPhone storyboard to the iPad storyboard.  When i do this, I see a large Lock icon and nothing happens.  I assume I have some setting messed up but I can't figure out where (Localization Locking is set to Nothing).

Answer (score 0):

@koregan's advice has worked for me.

1) Duplicate your iPhone-Storyboard and rename it MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard

2) Open this file any text editor.

3) Search for targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"and change it to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"

4) Now save everything and reopen Xcode -> the iPad-Storyboard contains the same as the iPhone-file but everyting could be disarranged

Comment: Hi, I did use @koregan's advice, and I used it to create my new storyboard.  But since I added just one new View Controller, I was wondering if there was an easier way to copy a single screen over to the iPad.