# interface builder shows all ipad views squished together

Tags: xcode, ipad, storyboard, interface-builder

I converted an iphone xib to ipad via [this helpful approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694985/1462372) but now all of my views are tightly packed in together in interface builder (screenshot: [IB views squished together](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w67qkn0xpdxy4oy/ZqhuufpQHP#lh:null-stackoverflow%20screenshot%20IB%20views%20squished.png)).

I cannot drag and drop them to spread them out. The UI is unresponsive to dragging. Appreciate suggestions... wondering if there is some additional change to the XIB XML for the conversion from iphone, or if there's an IB setting to allow dragging the views.

Comment: Drag and drop should do it just zoom in don't try and do it from that distance that was in the image you will not get very far as it will not be responsive.

Comment: Yeah, already tried that - all zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Popeye's response, I got the idea to try a mouse directly connected to the Mac, since I have been using **ShareMouse** to remotely mouse from a PC (Windows 7). This solved it.

Appears to be a bug in ShareMouse or an interaction bug between ShareMouse and IB. I could select any of the views, but drag did not work. (Dragging works just fine with ShareMouse on other things in and outside of xcode.) I will drop a note to the ShareMouse guys.