# Segue Identifier on iPad Storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app set up with collection views one has a series of cells on then segues to another with a full screen cell on to recreate a photo gallery. I have this working fine on the iPhone but when I try on iPad clicking on the first cell should recognise item at index path and pass this to the full screen view, which is not happening.

I believe the reason to be I am looking for a segue identifier and as this is a universal app am using the same code for both uses. On the iPhone storyboard I am able to set the segue identifier but this does not appear in the iPad storyboard. The question is…. Is this normal and is there a way around it? I can provide code on request but didn't feel it relevant to the question at this time.

Code is:

First Collection View

```
@implementation Study3CollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createData];
}

- (void)createData {

    self.dresserImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4723.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4726.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4729.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4730.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4731.JPG", @"image", nil]];


    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dresserImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *dresserImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    dresserImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.dresserImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 1) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.dresserImages count]) {
            self.title = self.dresserImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"collectionView"])

    {
        Study3DetailCollectionViewController *destViewController = (Study3DetailCollectionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

        destViewController.startingIndexPath = indexPath;

        [destViewController.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];

        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.startingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Detail View

```
@implementation Study3DetailCollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createData];
}

- (void)createData {

    self.dresserImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4723.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4726.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4729.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4730.JPG", @"image", nil]];
    [self.dresserImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Newton Wardrobes", @"name",
                                   @"IMG_4731.JPG", @"image", nil]];


    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dresserImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *dresserImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    dresserImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.dresserImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 1) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.dresserImages count]) {
            self.title = self.dresserImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.itemSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.startingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you set the identifier on both storyboards?

Comment: Yes, you should provide codes, especially `prepareForSegues:sender:` part

Comment: You have to set segue identifier for iPad storyboard separately if you r app is a universal app

Comment: What I mean by it doesn't appear is I am not given the option to enter it, the tab where you would normally enter this just says not applicable where as on the iPhone tab it is there and I can enter it. iPhone works absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the tab please? :)

Comment: The code is irrelevant for your problem. You should simply remove it from the question. As @Fogmeister pointed it out, you must set the segue identifiers manually, they are not automatically synchronized between storyboards. You should use the debugger to inspect the parameters of `prepareForSegue:sender:`, the segue will not have the id you are looking for if it is not set in the storyboard.

Comment: I did say the code was irrelevant but as I was asked for it I put it up however…. I have solved the problem I'm not awake yet and have been staring at this for a while all of the time it was actually hidden! I know what an idiot! thanks for all the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Just seen that you said "does not appear in the iPad storyboard".

It won't just appear without setting it yourself.

You'll need to go into the iPad storyboard file and set the segue identifier again in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same storyboard as of iPhone with iPad, then you could simply copy the contents of iPhone storyboard and paste it iPad storyboard. Things would be misplaced but if using auto layout it would be fixed at run time. Or you could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)