# Black Frame Around iPad Build

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I made an iPhone app under universal applications. Deleted the iPad storyboard at the start and added it back in using this answer: [Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad) at a later stage.

Now when I run my iPad build, there seems to be a black border around it.[image]

I've made sure my .plist is using `Main_iPad` for `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found my bug: this is because under Deployment Info in the General tab, I selected only iPhone as my Devices. Changing it to Universal fixed it.

Comment: I am making app for iPhone only , but is there by any chance that Apple may reject my app because its not showing proper UI as phone on the iPad?

Comment: Make sure you select it on the right target, when having multiple targets. Made me scratch my head for a while. ;)

Comment: @KunalGupta Yes they will reject if the UI is not proper for iPad. "We noticed that your app did not run or display as expected when viewed on iPad running iOS 11.3.1. Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use your app on iPad. "  - Reply from Apple

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking, this looks like just a scaled-up version of iPhone app. Anyways, to make it work in a better shape you may have to tweak here :

1. Make sure you have added constraints that actually meeting the iPad size requirements as well. The width & the Heights.
2. **Please provide a `launchImage` for iPad size.** That should solve your problem.

Hope that helps.