# Converting iPhone app to Universal, XCode 5.1 and Storyboards. Bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I just updated my XCode to 5.1.
My application is targeting iOS 7 and it has 1 single storyboard that it is targeting iPhone only.

Now I need to convert my app from iPhone only to Universal.

When changing the devices from iPhone to Universal I get prompt to if I want to copy the storyboard or not. I click on copy. After selecting Copy I get a new folder called iPad that it is empty and I continue to only have 1 Storyboard (the iPhone one).
However, the iPad section of the application is now referencing a storyboard called "Main-iPad" which does not exist. I believe this storyboard should've been created automatically.
If I run the app in the iPad emulator, the app runs but the console outputs this:

```
NSMainNibFile and UIMainStoryboardFile are both set. NSMainNibFile ignored.
```

If I chose not to copy, then the iPad folder does not get created and I continue with 1 storyboard and the ipad is referencing the iPhone storyboard (the only storyboard I have).

I can replicate this with a single view brand new project as well.
Also, XCode 5.1 does not seem to let me duplicate my storyboard or change the type of an existing storyboard from iPhone to iPad.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - it's a bug under iOS7. To fix the error message go into the .plist and delete the line that specifies the iPad xib name. You'll just then have to copy the iPhone storyboard and rename iPad-Main.

Comment: But when I copy and rename the iPhone storyboard, the storyboard remains as iPhone type. The "new" storyboard does not have the look and dimensions of the ipad storyboard.
Is there a way to change that? Can I change a storyboard from being iPhone to being iPad?

Comment: Yep - see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad

Comment: Ahh, that works but it also seems to need additional changes.
The "toolsVersion" and the "systemVersion" also needed to change in my case for the new storyboard to compile.

I had to change it to this:
'toolsVersion="5023" systemVersion="13A603"'

Comment: Now I have another problem though. The Storyboard compiles and I can edit it, but the iPad simulator continues to use the iPhone storyboard.
I've checked the plist, the app configuration, the folder position...everything seems right, but the iPad continues to not use the new storyboard :(