# Ipad app form universal app different size

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, xcode-storyboard

Hi first at all i converted my iphone app to universal and followed this steps ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad][1])  to convert my iphone storyboard to an ipad storyboard but now i have a problem in the size of the views here are the sceenshots.

And here is the ipad new view

Now what should i do ? Should I apply auto layout or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resize/change your views and constraints so it looks how you want it to on the iPad.

You probably need to add code to detect which storyboard to load depending on whether your app is running on an iPhone or iPad.  For more information, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/userInterfaceIdiom).