# Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "Main_iPad.storyboard"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i get the above error when trying to archive my app ready for uploading, not sure what it means, i first got an error that said the main iPad storyboard was missing so i copied the iPhone storyboard  and then changes the source to tell it, it was an iPad storyboard (followed another question on here) [image]

the code i've highlighted is part of the code i changed, i also changed         `"targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`

following this question, [Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)

any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: From your Storyboard, Utilities (on the right) > File Inspector (first on the left, looks like a document). Under Name YourStoryboard.storyboard, what does is say for 'Type'?

Comment: Default Interface Builder abstract storyboard

Comment: Do you have a  "Default Interface Builder **Cocoa Touch** Storyboard" in pop menu there? Is so, give it a shot.

Comment: nah its not an option?

Comment: I sometimes get this being stuck in a version comparison mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'targetRuntime' should be "iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" for iPad storyboards.
One of mines :

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9531" systemVersion="15C50" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" propertyAccessControl="none" initialViewController="XXX-XXX-XX">
```

You can right-click on your storyboard file inside Xcode file inspector and click "Open as source-code" then update this value.