# How to Convert iPhone app to support iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I have existing iPhone app. Now i want it to give support for iPad app i Followed the below link ([Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)). After implementing the suggestions given by tharkay. I run the app in iPad only Navigation bar coming properly but all components(like buttons, labels)are not resizing those are coming as iPhone size.

Can anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: did you used autolayout in your storyboard ?

Comment: That is the reason your uicontrols are not responding to different screen size. You must set constraints on your UI elements so that they can arrange themselves on different screen sizes by using AutoLayout. Check out this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Thanks i will sea the tutorial and let you know the progress

Answer (score 2):

Under your Project->Targets->General->Deployment Info make sure that in your iPad tab the right Main Interface is selected (it's your iPad storyboard name).
[image]

Comment: I tried this but screen size coming same as iPhone screen size

Comment: Have you tried to resize the elements and adding constraint to the view?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Comment: in the storyboard for iPad you've created your layout is the same as the one for iPhone right? If so, try to move the elements on the views in order to adjust the layout to fit the iPad screen

Comment: @ReddyBasha that's what I told u to add constraints to your ui elements using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autolayout` to setup the `constraints` on the `UI Elements` so that they can respond appropriately to different screen size like in your case iPad. Check out this link !

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1