# Creating iPad split storyboard View from iPhone storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have iPhone storyboard with `tabBarController`
I need to create iPad storyboard based on `viewControllers` from iPhone storyboard.

I created iPad storyboard with `splitView` and placed `splitViewController` but I have still running iPhone version with `tabBar` and without `splitView`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you selected your Storyboard for iPad in the projects settings? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058265/how-to-convert-iphone-app-to-support-ipad/26060628#26060628

Comment: Have you selected the Universal device deployment type?

Comment: yes, of course and I add iPad's storyboard

Comment: Yes to both questions?

Comment: yes, yes to both questions

Comment: Can you share some more information about your project and possibly share the code from -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ?