# How to migrate from iPhone/iPad storyboards to universal storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5, xcode6, ios-universal-app

I have a project created in Xcode 5. The "Deployment Info" settings says Devices: Universal but has separate iPhone and iPad settings and corresponding iPhone and iPad storyboards.

Now I'm developing the *same* project in Xcode 6 and I want to use one universal storyboard instead of two storyboards. I have only worked on the iPhone storyboard and haven't touched the iPad one. Is it possible to ditch the iPad storyboard and convert the existing iPhone storyboard to be my main universal storyboard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I adapted [this tutorial](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-convert-your-iphone-storyboard-into-an-ipad-storyboard/) and a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694985/703161) by @tharkay to create this solution below.

- Rename `Main_iPhone.storyboard` to `Main.storyboard`
- Delete `Main_iPad.storyboard`
- ***If you want to use the iPad storyboard instead of the iPhone, rename the `Main_iPad.storyboard` to `Main.storyboard` and delete the `Main_iPhone.storyboard` file. You will then need to go to the File Inspector and right-click your storyboard, then select “Open as Source Code”. This will display all that XML code. Change `targetRuntime` from `"iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"` to `"iOS.CocoaTouch"`

From:

```
targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
```

to:

```
targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"
```

- In the project file, under general settings, select `Main.storyboard` for both iPhone and iPad.

[image]

- On `Main.storyboard`, on the right-hand panel choose the `Show the File inspector` icon.

[image]

- Check the box named `Use Size classes`

[image]

- XCode will prompt with an Xcode 5 compatibility message, Select YES.
- Compile and run.
- Of course, all your views should be messed up and you'll need to redo auto-layout.

Answer (score 4):

In xCode 9 I also had to add `useTraitCollections="YES"` property into document tag (same place where `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"` is).

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution and it worked for me.

Duplicate your `MainStoryboard` and rename as `MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard` from the `File` menu

Now Right click on your MainStoryboard_iPad file and click on `open as a source code`.

You will get an XML document.
Now make some changes in XML file as below.

Search for `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`  and change it to `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"`

Remove The type = `"retina4"` as From 
`<simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" type="retina4"/>` 
 to

```
<simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
```

Again open the `MainStoryboard_iPad` file in interface builder. 
Hurray... You will get your iPad version storyboard. Now you just need to change the width and height as per your Layout.

This helped me alot and saved alot time.

:) Im sure it will help you!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking for a way to convert the iphone storyboard to a *single* universal storyboard, rather than having two storyboards.

Comment: @DogEatDog - Yes, this helped me alot and saved my 1-2 days. :) You can try it yourself.