# Project modernization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, size-classes

I have a project that started on 2008 and had been updated yet. Now I want to implement size classes and I find myself without being able to create universal xibs. I looked at the project settings and I have two "Main Interface" windows, as you can see here:

[image]

As a comparison, here is the same portion of a new project created with Xcode 7 & iOS 9

[image]

How can I update the project so that I can create universal, size-classes-using XIB files?

Comment: Can't you create a new storyboard file, and then set it as a "Main Interface"?

Comment: Unfortunately no; As you can see in the first screenshot, there is an "iPhone" and "iPad" buttons. In comparison the new project does not have that.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070572/how-to-migrate-from-iphone-ipad-storyboards-to-universal-storyboard) to another SO post may help.