# Using Single Storyboard for iPhone & iPad on Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard, universal, xcode5.1.1

I have been developing an iOS App with iPhone(4-inch) Storyboard. Now I would like to use the same storyboard for iPad also. My iPhone storyboard contains 130+ scenes now.
I need to make it for iPad also.

I tried solution from link:
[Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)

After following it my **Xcode crashes**, may be due to many scenes in the single storyboard.

I know about size classes in Xcode 6 and also tried it but the fonts don't update for the iPad size class(Regular Width| Regular Height) on simulator/device with iOS 7  but on iOS 8 it does. Since I have deployment target as iOS 7 I can't overlook the issue.

Can anyone help me with a solution that works on **Xcode 5.1.1** of having same iPhone storyboard for iPad(Like a Universal App) as well?

Any help/clue will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using size classes?

If that doesn't work, you could always use 2 different storyboards- 1 for the iPhone and 1 for the iPad

Comment: yes I did try using size class but the fonts don't update for iPad with iOS 7 with Regular Width and Regular Height...