# iPad3 treats my iPad app as an iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I had an iPhone app that I needed to convert to be iPad compatible.
I added an iPad stroyboard as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694985/2336573) and even changed it so that it could be iPad only.
The iPad layout shows up fine on all iPad simulators and when i run it on an ipad2 device. But when i run it on an iPad 3 device, it shows the iPhone layout instead and the scale factor (x2, x1) shows up in the upper right corner of the screen.
I already added an iPad launchImage,  and App icon. my info.plist contains both iPhone and iPad storyboard names.

what could cause the iPad3 to treat the app as iPhone given that it works fine on iPad2 device and all simulators ?

**UPDATE:**

Turned out the iPad was jailbroken and had RetinaPad installed (from cydia). Removed it and everything worked well.

Comment: Try adding Launch image (iPad). And also change the devices in target of your project to universal/iPad.

Comment: already done that, tried universal and iPad as well. still same result

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an older version of your app in your iPad or your resources are cached.

First of all be sure that in your project definitions the devices is set to "Universal".

[image]

Then, if this is set, remove the app from the iPad then do a force clean in XCode (go to Product then press alt and then click "Clean Build Folder"). Then run in the iPad again.

Comment: My money is on the devices setting. (Voted)

Comment: The only guess I have left (considering that runs in the iPad 2 and not in the iPad 3) is that the launch image is not defined for iPad 3.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida .The launchImage shows when running the on the iPad3. shouldn't it show a black screen instead if it was defined ?

Comment: @DuncanC i just checked the device, and other iPad apps are running fine. One thing I noticed though is that the device is jailbroken.