# Converting Storyboard to iPad from iPhone storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I wanna convert storyboard from iPhone to iPad. So i tried this answer.

[Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)

When i opened the new iPad Storyboard, it just shows the error as below:

[image]

So how can i resolve this?? Or Give me suggestions to convert to iPad Storyboard. I'm using Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: Please show your update in storyboard, maybe there is some mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Make sure your projects setting is in Universal
- Add key "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" in your plist file with MainStoryboard_iPad as the value

Comment: Already did these changes.. But Can't Open Storyboard for iPad

Comment: You might mistyped something in the xml file if you opened the _iPad storyboard as source code.