# Scaling Storyboard from iphone to ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard

Im trying to convert iPhone app storyboard to iPad. I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694985/2516538 to convert the storyboard to iPad, but the views are not scaled.

In order to scale them, I need to edit each view controller (~50) and scale all views inside (~20+).

I'm not using Size Classes or Auto Layout, I used autosizing for iPhone Storyboard [ To make it scale in iPhone screen sizes ], but it does not scale well in iPad [ so I removed autosizing it iPad storyboards ].

Do I have to edit each view controller and views inside them, or there is another way to do make the job easier?

Comment: There is definitely only one way to make your life easier: finally learn how Auto-Layout and Size Classes work and use this knowledge. The link you provided stinks a bit: its 2016 now and at least 4 different screen sizes you have/want to support

Comment: @slxl the thing is I'm working with an old app, and making it auto layout would take me more time to make it that doing it manually.

Comment: @iJizJaz of course its up to you, but I would think with perspective too. What you want to do won't make your app 'younger' - you will just have another 'old app' which is still hard to support. And every time you want to change something in this app - a little kitten dies somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give support for both then use size class, `any width any height` for ipad and `compact width regular height` for iphone. (assume portrait only).

when giving constraint `any any` then meke view controller's size as ipad size from `simulated metrics` and when give `c width r height` then make iphone size from same. first set constraint from `any any` and then fron `compact regular`. add constraint in compact regular size class and `uninstall constraint of any any for this size class` and vise versa.

you should first clear your old constrains and then start from first as mentioned above. hope this will help :)