# How to duplicate iPad storyboard into iPhone storyboard including language strings?

Tags: swift

I created a storyboard that I want only to apply to iPads, and I want to duplicate it to create a separate storyboard for the iPhone. I'm trying to get the new iPhone storyboard to have the same localizable strings as the iPad one. Is there any way to do this?

This is the entire iPad storyboard I'm trying to duplicate:

[image]

Comment: Didn't vote to close, but I am finding your issue very hard to duplicate because of how vague it is. Generally, both iPad and iPhone apps have the same storyboard - unless *your* app says otherwise. Can you provide more details for us to duplicate? EDIT: In case I'm assuming some things, have you checked info.plist? Do you have a separate storyboard defined based on the device?

Comment: @dfd Edited my question to be more clear. I had a storyboard I created just for iPads and I wanted to duplicate it to create a storyboard just for iPhones, but I was having trouble duplicating the base storyboard and all the localizable strings at once. However, I realized that I just had to create a separate iPhone storyboard how you normally would (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad) and then go to the localization section of the separate iPhone storyboard file inspector and check the right languages