# Converting iOS Storyboard to tvOS

Tags: ios, tvos

Is there an way where we can convert the iOS storyboard into an tvOS storyboard so that we can use the same storyboard already created once.

Comment: fortunately now relatively easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814523/294884