# Convert iPhone project to iPad project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm just starting out with iOS development and I'm actually trying to make an iPad application. I've found a sample project that is perfect for me to start from but it's meant as an iPhone app.

So I was wondering, maybe it's just a matter of replacing some xml file to convert it into an iPad app?

Any ideas if it can be done, and how?

Comment: [Is this relevant?](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1242.png)

Comment: This can help to [convert iphone xib to ipad xib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488280/converting-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 4, select the application target and change the value of **Devices**  in the **Summary** tab to **iPad**.

You should also modify the appropriate xib files made for iPhone. You may also have to change any code that works only for the iPhone like specifying frames with fixes values that fit the iPhone screen size, but are too small for the iPad screen size.