# ios registering document in document files

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gpx

I am working on app that reads gpx (topografix) file attached to an email. I have successfully registered this document type to my app so whenever I select such a file I get the option to open it by this app on iPhone. It works fine on my iPhone but on iPad my app is not recognised for opening such a file so my app does not appear on the list of apps that are capable to open it. This app uses iPhone environment and is set for iPhone not for universal environment. By changing on universal environment does not change anything. Why is my app not recognised in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Well  the conversion of an iphone app to ipad app has to be done if you want to make it universal.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488280/converting-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib)

Comment: Ok does it mean that I have to create same app but with configuration for iPad to make my app recognisable for opening gpx files on iPad? Generally, I expect iPhone apps running same way on iPad as well with difference in graphics resolution, am I wrong?

Comment: only xibs for ipad has to be created and some classes such as  which not works for ipad have to be replaced by appropriate class.           Example:replace  imagepickercontroller by popovercontroller