# Xib ipad window size small

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I converted iPhone xib to ipad xib. I referred this link [Converting iPhone xib to iPad xib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488280/converting-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib). But after deploy to ipadm, the view size is too small. It displaying center of the screen. It won't display 768x1024 screensize.

code:

```
NSString *aboutFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"
                                                              ofType:@"html"];

    NSLog(@"%@",aboutFilePath);


    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:aboutFilePath
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:nil];

    NSString *aPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *anURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aPath];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:anURL];
```

[image]

Comment: For the view that is not covering the whole screen, what is its autoresizing mask? Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: @DanielMartin: Check my edited code. And in File Inspector i checked Use AutoLayout also..It's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the app Universal, in Xcode go to your project settings, under the General tab, and change Devices: iPhone to Universal

[image: App type selector]

Comment: Some screenshots would be great

Comment: please check screenshot

Comment: Take a screenshot when you click the project file at the top of the left list of files...